# Why does this factorial function not work?

Tags: c

I tried to figure out how to do a factorial by myself, so it's messy but I was confused in certain aspects such as this one. Within fact() I type `fact(x,j)`. And this works. However my original attempt which had `fact(&x,j)` did not work. Why is that? Shouldn't the latter parameter work because I'm sending in the address of x, which I already set to n*n-1 in `*x = (*x)*j;`

```
int main(void)
{
    int x =0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int j =x;
    fact(&x, j);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    scanf("%d", &x);
}

int fact(int *x, int j)
{
    if(j!=1)
    {
        j = j-1;
        *x = (*x)*j;
        printf("j is : %d\n", j);
        fact(&x, j); //this is what i mean, remove the "&" and it works, but why?
    } else if(j==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If `x` is a pointer, and `&x` gives the location, why do I use `&x` in main but only `x` inside the function?

also not sure if return 0 or return 1 is the right thing to use to end a function.

Comment: It's more usual to return the factorial.

Comment: x is already a pointer inside fact. &x is a pointer to a pointer which is not what you want.

Comment: This not the same x. In main, x refers to the var declared as x in main as int. In fact to the parameter x of type int *.

Comment: Please enable warnings when you compile.  The compiler is very good at giving hints when things aren't quite right (like missing return statements...)

Comment: The simple answer (besides the missing return) that `&x` fails is that the function is already receiving a pointer.  `&x` is the address of that pointer - a pointer to a pointer.  A pointer to a pointer to an int is not the same as a pointer to an int.  Welcome to C pointer hell.

Comment: `x` is already a pointer; what you're doing by passing `&x` is adding another level of indirection which screws up dereferencing `x` down the call tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right here, as you mentioned:

```
fact(&x, j); //this is what i mean, remove the "&" and it works, but why?
```

This is passing a pointer to an `int *` (or a pointer to a pointer to an `int`) to `fact`.

Because `x` is an `int` in `main` and an `int *` in `fact`, you should just pass `x` to `fact` from within `fact`.

As you're using `*x` to access the `int` stored in `x` within `fact`, you should use `x` to get a pointer to that `int`.

Always `return 1` at the end of a function if it succeeds so that `if(func())` works.

As a side note, you should probably `return` the result of the recursive call from within `fact`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function's first argument is a pointer to an integer and pointer is a variable that holds an address so you need to pass the address when calling the function.That's why you pass **&x** to function as (&) gives the address of the variable

---

On the other hand inside the function , you have a pointer that holds an address to integer , so if you want to deference this pointer you should use (*) before pointer name.That's why you use **x** only inside the function.